# Why am I getting a "Not a valid JAR" while running a MR job on my local hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

This is the error precisely.

```
Alis-MacBook-Pro-2:hadoop aligajani$ hadoop jar /user/aligajani/job/wordcount.jar /user/aligajani/input /user/aligajani/input-output
Not a valid JAR: /user/aligajani/job/wordcount.jar
Alis-MacBook-Pro-2:hadoop aligajani$
```

1. Yes, I have copied the file in the HDFS.
2. Yes, I have verified that it is compiled correctly.
3. The example WordCount works just fine.

Comment: I think the jar should be in a local path (at least in the old API)

Comment: I made it work by using the JAR from my Desktop and I'm using 2.2.0

Comment: Great, I 'm adding this as an answer then, to close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the jar should be in a local path (at least in the old API).